# How does WebAuthn allow dependent web API's to access public key for decrypting credential without having to send the key?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, webauthn

I have familiarity with OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect but am new to WebAuthn. I am trying to understand how a scenario using those OAuth flows and connections would work using WebAuthn. I thought by mapping concepts from oauth to webauthn I would be able better understand the concepts.

I think similar to how in OAuth implicit grant flow a client may receive an id_token and access_token, in WebAuthn a client may receive a credential object from the Authenticator using [navigator.credential.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/create).

The part I do not understand is how this credential can reliably be consumed by downstream services. In OAuth a client or server may send "access_tokens" and the receiving servers may request the public keys from the authorities to validate that it hasn't been tampered, is not expired, has correct audience, etc.  This relies on the authorities having a publicly available [/.well-known endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig) with the public keys.

However, I think because the keys are specific to the authenticator instead of a single shared public key it is not possible to have these be discoverable.

This is where I don't understand how credentials could be consumed by services. I thought the client would have to send the public key WITH the authenticator and client data but this is 3 pieces of information and awkward. Sending a single access_token seems actually cleaner.

I created a graphic to explain visually.
(It may have technical inaccuracies, but hopefully the larger point is made clearer)
https://excalidraw.com/#json=fIacaTAOUQ9GVgsrJMOPr,yYDVJsmuXos0GfX_Y4fLRQ

Here are the 3 questions embedded in the image:

1. What data does the client need to send to the server in order for the server to use the data? (Similar to sending access_token)
2. How would sever get the public key to decrypt data?
3. Which piece of data is appropriate / standardized to use as the stable user id?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of good information in the other answers and comments which I encourage you to read. Although I thought it would be better to consolidate it in a single post which directly responds to the question from OP.

1. How does WebAuthN allow dependent web API's to access public key for decrypting credential without having to send the key?

   - There were problems with the question:

     - I used the word "decrypt" but this was wrong. The data sent is signed not encrypted and so key is not used to decrypted but verify the signature.
     - I was asking how a part of OAuth process can be done using WebAuthN however, this was misunderstanding. WebAuthN is not intended to solve this part of process so the question is less relevant and doesn't make sense to be answered directly.
   - Others have posted that WebAuthN can be used WITH OAuth so downstream systems can still receive JWTs and verify signatures as normal. How these two protocols are paired is a out of scope.
2. What data does the client need to send to the server in order for the server to use the data?

   - @Rafe answered: "table with user_id, credential_id, public_key and signature_counter"

     - See: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#authenticatormakecredential
3. How would server get the public key to decrypt data?

   - Again, decrypt is wrong word. Server is not decrypting only verifying signature
   - Also, the word server has multiple meanings based on context and it wasn't clarified in the question.

     - WebAuthN: For the server which acts as Relying Party in WebAuthN context, it will verify signature during authentication requests. However, the server in question was intended to mean the downstream APIs would not be part of WebAuthN.
     - OAuth: As explained by others, theses API servers could still be using OAuth and request public key from provider for verification and token contains necessary IDs and scopes/permissions. (Likely means able to re-use existing JWT middlewares)
4. Which piece of data is appropriate / standardized to use as the stable user id?

   - For WebAuthN the user object requires { id, name, displayName }. However, it intentionally does not try to standardize how the ID may propagated to downstream systems. That is up to developer.

     - See: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#dictdef-publickeycredentialuserentity
   - For OAuth

     - sub: REQUIRED. Subject Identifier. A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User

       - See: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenResponse

Hopefully I didn't make too many technical inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2):

As someone else mentioned - where there are a lot of commonalities between how WebAuthn and something like OpenID Connect work, they aren't really useful for understanding how WebAuthn works - they are better to explore after you understand WebAuthn.

A WebAuthn relying party does not have its own cryptographic keys or secrets  or persistent configuration - it just has a relying party identifier, which is typically the web origin. The client (browser and/or platform) mediate between the relying party and authenticators, mostly protecting user privacy, consent, and providing phishing protection.

The relying party will create a new credential (e.g. key pair) with the authenticator of a user's choosing, be it a cell phone or a physical security key fob in their pocket. The response is the public key of a newly created key pair on the authenticator. That public key is saved against the user account by the RP.

In a future authentication, the authentication request results in a response signed by that public key. The private portion is never meant to leave the authenticator - at least not without cryptographic protections.

This does pair well with something like OpenID Connect. The registration is normally by web domain, which means that there could be a lot of manual registrations necessary (and potentially management, and recovery, and other IAM type activities) necessary. With OpenID Connect, you can centralize the authentication of several applications at a single point, and with it centralize all WebAuthn credential management.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought by mapping concepts from oauth to webauthn I would be able better understand the concepts.

This seems to be working against you - you're trying to pattern match WebAuthn onto a solution for a different kind of problem (access delegation). Overloaded terminology around "authentication" doesn't help, but the WebAuthn specification does make things a bit more clear [when it describes what it means with "Relying Party"](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#webauthn-relying-party):

> Note: While the term Relying Party is also often used in other contexts (e.g., X.509 and OAuth), an entity acting as a Relying Party in one context is not necessarily a Relying Party in other contexts. In this specification, the term WebAuthn Relying Party is often shortened to be just Relying Party, and explicitly refers to a Relying Party in the WebAuthn context. Note that in any concrete instantiation a WebAuthn context may be embedded in a broader overall context, e.g., one based on OAuth.

Concretely: in your OAuth 2.0 diagram WebAuthn is used during step 2 "User enters credentials", the rest of it doesn't change. Passing the WebAuthn credentials to other servers is not how it's meant to be used, that's what OAuth is for.

To clarify one other question "how would sever get the public key to decrypt data?" - understand that WebAuthn doesn't encrypt anything. Some data (JS `ArrayBuffer`s) from the authenticator response is typically base64 encoded, but otherwise the response is often passed to the server unaltered as JSON. The server uses the public key to verify the signature, this is either seen for the first time during registration, or retrieved from the database (belonging to a user account) during authentication.

Comment: 1. "[Attempting to match WebAuthn onto OAuth concepts] seems to be working against you", Ok. I will stop trying to think of WebAuthN in OAuth terms.
2. "how would sever get the public key to decrypt data? ... The server uses the public key to verify the signature". By verify, do you mean encrypt the data and see if it matches signature? Similar to verifying OAuth signature.

Comment: I had though the server sends challenge (random bits) to client, client sends challenge to authenticator to encrypt, client sends encrypted data back to server, this decrypts and checks if challenge is matches the original. This is how it knows the credential object it receives was from itself. (Although I suppose looking at a signed data containing host URL would suffice.

3. "retrieved from the database (belonging to a user account) during authentication" I think is the part I am most interested in. The process of storing certain pieces of information in a database

Comment: This is good information, but I don't think it directly enough answers any of the 4 questions in the post.

Comment: You're correct that the server sends a random challenge to the client (browser) but the the authenticator signs (not encrypts!) the data. The exact data returned depends on whether it is an attestation (registration) or assertion (authentication) operation, the authenticator public key is only sent as part of the attestation response (and included in the attestation signature) for example. See the spec for more: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-authenticator-model and https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#authenticatormakecredential or https://webauthn.guide/ for a step-by-step guide.

Comment: In terms of what to store, step 23 of https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#authenticatormakecredential lists this. Users can have multiple WebAuthn credentials so a separate table with user_id, credential_id, public_key and signature_counter columns would work. At https://github.com/herrjemand/awesome-webauthn you can find libraries and example implementations.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Added picture for a clearer understanding of how webauthn works, since it has nothing to do with OAuth2 / OpenID.

[image: WebauthN Diagram]
(source: https://passwordless.id/protocols/webauthn/1_introduction)

---

Interestingly enough, what I aim to do with [Passwordless.ID](https://passwordless.id) is a free public identity provider using webauthn and compatible with OAuth2/OpenID.

Here is the demo of such a "Sign in" button working with OAuth2/OpenID:

https://passwordless-id.github.io/demo/

Please note that this is an early preview, still in development and somewhat lacking regarding the documentation. Nevertheless, it might be useful as working example.

---

That said, I sense some confusion in the question. So please let me emphasize that OAuth2 and WebAuthN are two completely distinct and unrelated protocols.

WebAuthN is a protocol to authenticate a user device. It is "Hey user, please sign me this challenge with your device to prove it's you"

OAuth2 is a protocol to authorize access to [part of] an API. It is "Hey API, please grant me permission to do this and that on behalf of the user".

OpenID builds on OAuth2 to basically say "Hey API, please allow me to read the user's standardized profile!".

WebauthN is not a replacement for OAuth2, they are 100% independent things. OAuth2 is to authorize (grant permissions) and is unrelated to how the user actually authenticates on the given system. It could be with username/password,  it could be with SMS OTP ...and it could be with WebauthN.

Comment: There is very little in common between WebAuthn and OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect. Trying to compare them may actually be more confusing.

Comment: 1. "Trying to compare [WebAuthn and OAuth 2.0]may actually be more confusing" (from Tim). I think he may have replied to the wrong post. I think this was my mistake in OP, but I think dagnelies agrees and was not comparing.
2. "WebauthN is not a replacement for OAuth2, they are 100% independent things" Oh. I thought they were intended to have parallel feature sets. From you samples questions I think you are saying WebAuthN could authenticate the user, then use OAuth2 to grant permissions to this user. Then JWT tokens can be sent to downstream systems as normal.

Comment: Similar to my comment above. I was hoping for more direct responses to the 4 questions. 

I think you are saying:
1. "How does "  WebAuthN is not concerned with providing information to dependent WebAPIs it is ONLY authenticating the user. Any downstream services must be provided access using other protocols.
2. "What data ..." Server would have to store public key, and user data during registration. (Although it's still unclea)
3. "How ..." The server doesn't decrypt, it only verifies signature
4. "Which ..." I think the server implementation can define user id, it is NOT standardized

Comment: @MattMazzola to be blunt, your questions are difficult to answer because comparing two protocols that have nothing in common makes no sense. I suspect the reason is a deeper misunderstanding on how both protocols work, that's why I wanted to at least clarify their purpose.